# Software for documenting the relationship between various objects of a software project (Software Architecture)

Tags: project-management, mind-mapping, documentation-viewer, mapping, dependencies

It's my first question on this forum so my title and question may not be structured properly.

We are about to recreate a software project, for optimization, that the development team has already done on a certain technology/platform.

At this stage I am aware of most of the different types of objects, similar to Tables etc, that make up the whole software project "stack", and I would like to document them and their dependencies / relations to one an another.

Since we are recreating it, it would be easy to document as we go.

I hope this model / interactive dependency graph will allow us to select any node and understand all the other objects it is related to. This would give us an idea of the all the objects that would be affected if we update one particular object.

We don't need a UML software as they just give static output of the same, we require a dynamic / interactive modeler that would allow us to get insight of the overall software architecture, such as the relations / dependencies of a particular object and all related objects to it in a visual manner.

Upon searching online, I have found relevant models / software, but they don't exactly match our usecase, such as: Sourcetrail, VS's code map and Structurizr.

Comment: Might be useful to mention which computer languages are used currently.

Comment: @albert [1/2] True I can understand why that information would be useful. I have found software that parses through your code and creates a interactive model around that.
In our case, we don't want to parse any of our code to automatically and generate a model. Our project spans multiple domains of development and many platforms and architectures.

Comment: [2/2] What I can mention, that would be helpful in understanding the scenario, is that imagine with have an API service that is created by a bunch of 'objects' acting as data sources linked together and a React App consumes it, if we update one of the data sources, we would like to first check it against the interactive model to see the API's it affects and the higher level React Apps it would affect. This is just an example, we are using many such technologies / platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is https://www.pathwaysystems.com/.
Their features cover my requiments.

Comment: Can you point out what features does it have in comparison with your request?